# Selenium WebDriverManager when the internet is down

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager

We are using Selenium WebdriverManager to make sure the version of Selenium Webdriver matches the current version of Chrome. It serves its purpose well.

However, there is a problem when we lose our internet connection. At this point, Chrome is obviously not updating, so provided we have already downloaded the version of the driver that matches our current Chrome version, things ought to be able to work. However, WebDriver setup fails with the exception

```
System.Net.WebException: 'No such host is known. (chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443)'
```

We are setting up the driver as follows:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
var manager = new DriverManager();
var chromeConfig = new ChromeConfig();
manager.SetUpDriver(chromeConfig, WebDriverManager.Helpers.VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser); // throws here
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to tweak the setup so that if it can't access the internet, it will still use the last-used driver, provided it should still work with current Chrome.

I did try catching and ignoring the exception, but it just throws at the next line.

Comment: You could catch and ignore the exception. You don't need to call `manager.SetUpDriver` to run Selenium tests, that's done to install the driver if it's missing. It's something that only needs to happen once per test session.

Comment: You might try implementing your own [BinaryService](https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net/blob/master/WebDriverManager/Services/Impl/BinaryService.cs). As long as your class implements [IBinaryService](https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net/blob/master/WebDriverManager/Services/IBinaryService.cs) you might be able to program a fallback.